# Turn values from table into column headers

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I'm trying to take values from rows of a table and turn them into column headers. For example, my table currently looks like this:

```
 _id   question_id   category
----- ------------- ----------
  1    767           back
  1    768           dev
  2    768           dev
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
 _id   767      768
----- -------- -----
  1    back     dev
  2    (null)   dev
```

I have found solutions on here using `CASE/WHEN`, but I am getting errors when trying to implement the solutions. My code is below. In this case, I am getting a `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` error at the end of line 6. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT
 msr._id,
 ans.question_id,
 ans.category,

 CASE ans.question_id WHEN '767' THEN ans.category END '767',
 CASE ans.question_id WHEN '768' THEN ans.category END '768'

FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1._id = t2._id

WHERE t2.question_id in (767,768) AND t2.assigned_to not in ('Smith, John')
 AND t1.request_type_id in (288,289) and t1.status_id not in (0, 11);
```

Comment: I guess you might have a lot more question ids than what is given here?  If so just search Stack for dynamic oracle pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

' is the delimiter for string literals. " is for column names. Hence:

```
 CASE ans.question_id WHEN '767' THEN ans.category END "767",
 CASE ans.question_id WHEN '768' THEN ans.category END "768"
```

Comment: It's always the little things. Thanks! But now I have another problem... If there is an `_id` with both a 767 and 768 `question_id`, I get two rows for that `_id`, one where there is a 767 value and `null` value for 768, and the reverse. Thoughts on how to fix this?