# ORA-00923: expected - got CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a query that uses `GROUP BY`, so I need to put the selected items in either the `GROUP BY` or in an aggregate function. When I put put them in the `GROUP BY`, `t2.category` throws the error in the title. I tried incorporating an aggregate function in the `CASE/WHEN` statements instead of putting `t2.category` in the `GROUP BY`, but I get an `invalid identifier` error. An example of `t2.category` could be "Server Reliability -- connection issues because of db dropout". How can I get rid of this error?

```
SELECT
 msr._id,

 CASE ans.question_id WHEN '767' THEN ans.category END "767",
 CASE ans.question_id WHEN '768' THEN ans.category END "768"

FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1._id = t2._id

WHERE t2.question_id in (767,768) AND t2.assigned_to not in ('Smith, John')
 AND t1.request_type_id in (288,289) and t1.status_id not in (0, 11);

GROUP BY t1._id, t2.question_id, t2.category
```

Comment: I assume `t2.category` is a `clob` based on the error.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes. That's the piece that is causing the error.

Comment: [You can't group by a CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_sql_semantics.htm#ADLOB45594). You could group up to 4000 chars of it, but if that was OK you wouldn't need a CLOB in the first place. Why do you have a group by clause when you have no aggregates in the select list though? Is this only part of the query? If you do really have aggregates, show a representative query and the table structures, and maybe there's a way around - like joining to `t2` after the aggregation happens. Depends on your data though.

Comment: I don't have any aggregates. I tried using aggregates like FIRST() and MAX(), but I get an "invalid identifier" error. If there is an aggregate that works for `t2.category`, I would love to use it because I really don't need it in the group by. I haven't found one though, hence the post.

Comment: ^^^ The reason that I need a `GROUP BY` is that there are 2 lines for some `_id` values where `767` is (null) in one and `768` is (null) in the other. I want to combine the two rows. Here's a link to a question I asked earlier today explaining my initial problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119268/turn-values-from-table-into-column-headers/32119373#32119373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than only using the first 4000 characters of the CLOB value, which probably isn't acceptable, the only way I can see to get around the restictions on CLOBs ([including that you can't group by them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_sql_semantics.htm#ADLOB45594)) is to join to the second table multiple times:

```
SELECT
 msr.id,
 ans_767.category AS "767",
 ans_768.category AS "768"
FROM msr
LEFT OUTER JOIN ans ans_767
ON ans_767.id = msr.id
AND ans_767.question_id = 767
AND ans_767.assigned_to not in ('Smith, John')
LEFT OUTER JOIN ans ans_768
ON ans_768.id = msr.id
AND ans_768.question_id = 768
AND ans_768.assigned_to not in ('Smith, John')
WHERE msr.request_type_id in (288,289)
AND msr.status_id not in (0, 11);

        ID 767                  768                
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 back                 dev
         2                      dev
```

They are both left joins but mean you only get one row back, so don't have to collapse the values you get from two rows with your version.

I've had to move the `question_id` filter into each of the `ON` clauses; but I've also moved the `assigned_to` filter, as having it in the where clause turns the outer joins back into inner joins.

This is ugly but bearable for two question IDs, but doesn't scale well in terms of maintenance and readability.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ba86/1), using values from your previous question; and your original code (sort of; edited a bit) [failing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ba86/5).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @NoSocks - if you did still want a workaround with the first 4000 chars you'd use `dbms_lob.substr`, inside the `MAX()`. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ba86/6). If you're on 11gR2 you could also use `pivot` with the shorted values, which is what you're doing manually. If you're trimming the category lengths down that much there isn't much point having a CLOB column.